# AWS Lambda with Java unable to GET a file from S3

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I'm creating a very simple example with AWS Lambda and I have problem using Java runtime. I have to read a S3 object from a bucket of mine and with a NodeJS example like the following I have no problem

```
var S3FS = require('s3fs');

exports.handler = (req, res) => {
    var s3Options = {
        region: 'eu-west-3',
        accessKeyId: 'key',
        secretAccessKey: 'secret'
    };

    var fsImpl = new S3FS('mybucket', s3Options);

    fsImpl.readFile("myfile",function (err,data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}
```

If I try a similar Java example my function always timeouts (even if I increase to 1 minute)

```
context.getLogger().log("Before");
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("key", "secret");
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion("eu-west-3")
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
        .build();
context.getLogger().log("client created");
S3Object object = s3.getObject(
            new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
context.getLogger().log("After");
```

The function always blocks when creating the S3 client. I know I can avoid using the key and secret in the Lambda, but also in this way the function blocks. It isn't a policy problem because I'm testing these examples from the same Lambda configuration so I think it's something related to the Java AWS S3 API. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use getObjectAsString instead: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#getObjectAsString-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: I cannot use it because the function blocks when creating AmazonS3 client

Comment: Does your Java code successfully get an object if you run this code outside of Lambda? Also, are you deploying the Lambda function into a VPC (that does not have an outbound route to the internet)?

Comment: Yes it works outside Lambda and no I'm not deploying it into a VPC

Comment: Couldn't it be a proxy problem? Is your S3 accessible via AWS CLI from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

The Java lambda finally works using [defaultClient()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html#defaultClient--) and not [standard()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html#standard--) method of AmazonS3ClientBuilder.

The difference between these two methods are the credentials, retrieved from env or passed as arguments. There is probably a wrong configuration I don't see, but anyway a more clear error could be useful